# how to receive map<A, B>& from function/class?

Tags: c++, function, boost, dictionary, boost-extension

How to receive `map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> >` from such function?

So I have

```
template <class BaseClass, class ConstructorType>
map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> > get_factories (shared_library & lib) {
    type_map lib_types;
    if (!lib.call(lib_types)) {
        cerr << "Types map not found!" << endl;

    }

    map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> >& lib_factories(lib_types.get());
    if (lib_factories.empty()) {
        cerr << "Producers not found!" << endl;

    }
    return lib_factories;

}
```

and I try to get its value with something like:

```
map<string, factory<PublicProducerPrototype, int> > producer_factories();
producer_factories = get_factories<PublicProducerPrototype, int>(simple_producer);
```

I try to generalize/simplify some of boost.extension methods for myself.

So how to receive `map<A, B>&` correctly?

How to initialize link correctly or how to return not link but real object? (sorry C++ nube)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a reference to a map, you should declare the function as returning a reference, not a value:

```
template <class BaseClass, class ConstructorType>
map<string, factory<BaseClass, ConstructorType> >& get_factories (...
```

Of course, this assumes that the reference returned by `lib_types.get()` is safe to pass out as a reference.